# Form validation could not remove the required css on removeError function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I managed to make all fields are required and validated. But when I try to make a field not required it does not remove CSS.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group"><label for="">Your email addresss<span class=""></span></label><input type="email" class="form-control"><small style="display: none"></small></div>
```

**JS Code:**

```
var removeError = function (element, siblings) {
    $(element).removeClass("text-error");

    siblings.each(function (index, sib) {
        if (sib.tagName == "SMALL") {
            sib.innerText = ""
            $(sib).removeClass("text-danger");
            $(sib).removeClass("font-weight-bold");
            $(sib).hide();
        }
    })
};
```

I tried to experiment by removing CSS **class="text-danger"** even comment out the below line my function checks for that

```
 <!-- <small style="display: none"></small> -->
```

Why the above change does not work? 
How can I make this utility or configured work for none required field as well,

I am struggling is there any way I can set not required field, I don't want to use a third-party library (such as jQuery Validate plugin) for now as it is not working on my system. Because of most of them use "Form" tag, and could not be managed to use it without form tag.

Demo Code pen: **https://codepen.io/dunya/pen/KYdQPd**

Comment: Could you please provide a relevant codePen with the problem, not the whole code?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, I did further cleaning up of the code, thanks for the advise